# BI Publisher SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I am using BI Publisher.

I have placed a field in my report layout but I would like that  null data values are not displayed from this field, so that this null gap is not seen in my report.

How do I accomplish this ?

The manual does not help much.

Answer (score 0):

you have to select first the field,and then go to the data field tab and then in conditional formatting ,choose Highlight..
There you can choose white colour in order to disappear the value of the null

[image]

Comment: Hi Anastasis , I want that that if the value is null, the field does not appear  in the report, and therefore there is no gap or blank line

Comment: The field has some unique values and other values that are null.  I want the field to not show null values so that there is no gap in my report. I want the field to show the unique values however.

Comment: Also, i am not using a table. I am using a character string field that is creating a gap in the data when its value is null. eg. if a, b, c are fields .and is field b is null, there is a gap between a and c field information.

Comment: Undersand,i don't know any method to do this...
If you insert a text item,it will be there and there is no any conditonal method to disappear it...

Comment: Hi Anatasis, do you know or have you seen any coding that can do this ?

Comment: Hi,to be honest i have not seen any relative solution for this,but i don't know maybe,there is a solution if you use rtf template instead of the bi publisher layout

Comment: Hi Anatasis, do you work with BI Publisher.Do you have a professional email at which you can be contacted?

Comment: Thank you Anastasis! Do you guys have a professional contact number as well for BI-publisher?